# UITableView: changing footer view's size programmatically doesn't work

Tags: uitableview, uiview, frame, footer, tweets

My table view's footer is a view that shows some tweets from a user, so I do not know its height until I got the tweets, I created a `FooterViewController` that has a method `refreshTweets`, I add it in `viewDidLoad`:

```
FooterViewController *controller = [[FooterViewController alloc] initWithNibName...];
[[self tableView] setFooterView:[controller view]];
[controller refreshTweets];
```

in `refreshTweets` method, I read tweets and calculate the total height, and reset view(the footer)'s height:

```
self.view.frame = newFrame;
```

but it does not make sense, the footer's height is still the height I set in Interface Builder, is there anything missing or any alternative way of doing this?

Thanks!

edit:
I can change the view's size to be small enough in interface builder, and it will be enlarged after calculating tweets' height and setting view.frame, but the table view still thinks its footer has previous height, that is, the extra space is outside of the tableview and I can only see it if I drag the table up.

Answer (score 52, accepted):

```
myTable.tableFooterView = myFooterView;
```

Re-assign your footer view to the table. The table will recognize it has a new footer and re-do whatever layout needs to occur for the proper size of the footer.

Comment: One helpful (and more verbose) link might be this one about resizing the tableHeaderView; works perfectly for tableFooterView, too: http://davidjhinson.wordpress.com/2009/03/24/resizing-a-uitableviews-tableheaderview/

Comment: This doesn't work as of iOS11 but here's a similar answer which does: https://stackoverflow.com/a/28102175/918602

Answer (score 0):

In order to change the frame of footer view here is the simple tweak:-

In Swift:-

```
func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, heightForFooterInSection section: Int) -> CGFloat {
    return 0.5
}


func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, viewForFooterInSection section: Int) -> UIView? {
    let footerView = UIView()
    let footerChildView = UIView(frame: CGRect(x: 60, y: 0, width: tableView.frame.width - 60, height: 0.5))
    footerChildView.backgroundColor = UIColor.darkGray
    footerView.addSubview(footerChildView)
    return footerView
}
```

Comment: This question is about the footerView of the tableview, not for a specific section of the tableview, which is different.