# UITableView footer view covered by UITabBar

Tags: uitableview, uitabbarcontroller, uitabbar, spacing

I'm writing an iPhone application which displays a tableview with an header and a footer view. This table is include in a TabBar view controller which is included in a NavigationView controller. 
This means my tableview is included between a navigation bar and a tabbar. 
The problem is that the footer view (which includes a graph) gets partially covered by the tabbar. I tried to tweak the simulated metrics in the XCode Storyboard but apparently this values affect only the tableview and not the footer view.

Any idea?

Thanks a lot

Claus

Answer (score 0, accepted):

So you want to resize the height of the `UITableView's` footer view right?

Answer(s) is probably [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6672528/uitableview-changing-footer-views-size-programmatically-doesnt-work) then.