# systemLayoutSizeFittingSize:UILayoutFittingCompressedSize doesn't compress

Tags: objective-c, uitableview, ios7, ios8, autolayout

I have problems with auto layout and the UITableView header (tableHeaderView) in iOS 8.X e iOS7.x.

The `self.HeaderView` is a XIB built using auto layout. 
It's used inside a scrollviewer followed by other views and the result is correct.

Then I set it as header of a table view (as described [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16471846/is-it-possible-to-use-autolayout-with-uitableviews-tableheaderview)):

```
self.tableView.tableHeaderView = self.HeaderView;
[self.HeaderView setNeedsLayout];
[self.HeaderView layoutIfNeeded];
CGSize headerViewSize = [self.HeaderView systemLayoutSizeFittingSize:UILayoutFittingCompressedSize];
CGRect frame = self.HeaderView.frame;
frame.size.height = headerViewSize.height;
self.HeaderView.frame = frame;
self.tableView.tableHeaderView = self.HeaderView;
```

but the resulted height is bigger than expected. I can't understand why. Constraints seem to be ok otherwise why in the scrollview the result is correct?

If in the IB I resize the height of the container frame the constraints are updated without any ambiguity.

Why the `UILayoutFittingCompressedSize` doesn't compress the view?

**#update**

I discovered the problem. Basically the constraints are correct.

After layoutSubviews has been called the UIImageView is correctly sized. Width and height are as expected. 
The problem is in the way `systemLayoutSizeFittingSize:UILayoutFittingCompressedSize` works.

Instead of calculating the size using the UIImageView size (which has been correctly resized), it uses the size of UIImage (which source file is bigger)

So, what can I do to force `systemLayoutSizeFittingSize:UILayoutFittingCompressedSize` to calculate the size using the UIImageView size??

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Found the solution.

In few words, constraints were ok, on iOS 8 the `systemLayoutSizeFittingSize:UILayoutFittingCompressedSize` was working as expected but it didn't on iOS7.

For a pure coincidence I called the combination of

```
[self.HeaderView setNeedsLayout];
[self.HeaderView layoutIfNeeded];
```

twice and I noticed that in that way the *systemLayoutSizeFittingSize:UILayoutFittingCompressedSize* worked on iOS 7 too.

In that moment I realized that the solution was calling the combination above twice in sequence (not necessary on iOS 8)

*It would be nice to understand why...*

Answer (score -1):

Here's what I do: I create constraints for the header view to make its left and right equal to the tableview, with a priority of UILayoutPriorityDefaultHigh. I add these constraints to the tableView when the header view moves to a non-nil window in didMoveToWindow: and remove them when it gets removed from its superview in willMoveToSuperview. And once it is set up, I use systemLayoutSizeFittingSize but pass in self.frame, and then I set it as the tableHeaderView.

That seems to work fine, including with rotation. The order of adding/removing constraints is quite important to avoid warnings by UILayout.