# UIVIew from XIB with Autolayout to UItableView Header

Tags: objective-c, uitableview, xcode6, autolayout, xib

I am writing because I have a problem with the Auto Layout.
I'm trying to create a simple view in InterfaceBuilder with Auto Layout I want to load code and enter as a header of a table (not as header section). I explain briefly what are the characteristics.
The `imageView` must be square and must be as wide as the screen.
The space under the picture to the bottom of view that contains the button and label must be high 50 points.
Between image and button has to be a fixed distance of 12 points.
Between image and label must be a fixed distance of 13 points.

All these features are able to get them with Auto Layout. I added a constraint to the aspect ratio of the image (1: 1) and the various constraints for distances. all right.

The real problem is that by launching the app on iphone 6+ simulator (414 points of width), the image (with the label and button) goes above the cells.

Enabling various transparencies I noticed that the `superView` of Image View, only increase the width. It does not increase its height! How do I fix?

This is the code:

```
- (void)viewDidLoad{
//...    
PhotoDetailsHeaderView *hView = (PhotoDetailsHeaderView *)[[[NSBundle mainBundle] loadNibNamed:@"PhotoDetailsHeaderView" owner:self options:nil] objectAtIndex:0];
    hView.delegate = self;
    
    self.tableView.tableHeaderView = hView;
//...
}
```

This is how I create the xib:
[image: Interface builder xib creation]

and this is how it is on the simulator, the green box is Uiimageview and the yellow box (under green box) is the mainview (or superview):

[image]

How can fix it?

Many thanks to all!

Comment: Couldn't understand your problm,can u pls detail it out this complete view is your view above the tableView or this view is part of ur uitableview.

Comment: The view that i'm setting as a headerView is a Subclass of UIView: PhotoDetailsHeaderView *hView = (PhotoDetailsHeaderView *)[[[NSBundle mainBundle] loadNibNamed:@"PhotoDetailsHeaderView" owner:self options:nil] objectAtIndex:0];
    hView.delegate = self;
    
    self.tableView.tableHeaderView = hView;

Answer (score 1):

You'll need to add a property to store your `PhotoDetailsHeaderView`:

```
@property (nonatomic, strong) PhotoDetailsHeaderView *headerView;
```

Then calculate its expected frame in `viewDidLayoutSubviews`. If it needs updating, update its frame and re-set the `tableHeaderView` property. This last step will force the tableView to adapt to the header's updated frame.

```
- (void)viewDidLayoutSubviews{
    [super viewDidLayoutSubviews];

    CGRect expectedFrame = CGRectMake(0.0,0.0,self.tableview.size.width,self.tableView.size.width + 50.0);

    if (!CGRectEqualToRect(self.headerView.frame, expectedFrame)) {
        self.headerView.frame = expectedFrame;
        self.tableView.tableHeaderView = self.headerView;
    }
}
```

Comment: With this solution I get the desired result. Thank you. I was hoping to avoid writing code, I wanted to avoid writing in sizes in code but if cannot do it in other ways, that's okay. The result would be great to do everything with autolayout. very much cleaner ..

Comment: To achieve the same thing with auto layout you will need to calculate the frame using `systemLayoutSizeFittingSize:`. See http://stackoverflow.com/a/28102175

Comment: I tried but unfortunately the height is zero. It does not work in my case

Comment: That probably means your constraints allow for a zero height; perhaps nothing is pinned to the bottom of the superview. Will you be marking this answer as correct?

Answer (score 0):

The problem is probably that in iOS you have to reset the header of the table view manually (if it has changed its size). Try something along these lines:

```
CGRect newFrame = imageView.frame;
imageView.size.height = imageView.size.width;
imageView.frame = newFrame;
[self.tableView setTableHeaderView:imageView];
```

This code should be in `-(void)viewDidLayoutSubviews` method of your view controller.