# Automatic height with header cell in tableView

Tags: swift, uitableview, uikit, storyboard, tableview

I have a tableView with a header and below that a prototype cell which repeats himself. Both contain text label and are dynamic.

First picture is how it looks like right now. And the second one how it should look like.
I tried to add the prototype cell with auto layout 0 to the header view. But the auto layout is greyed out. How can I show both header and prototype cell without overlaying?

[image]

[image]

Comment: Does this answer your question? [UITableView header dynamic height in run-time](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/44195986/uitableview-header-dynamic-height-in-run-time)

Comment: Thanks. I tried this and it worked! https://useyourloaf.com/blog/variable-height-table-view-header/