# How to hide custom view above tableview

Tags: ios, swift, xcode

I have a `tableView` with a `UIView` inside it and I want with the tap of a button to disappear the view.

Because the `UIView` is inside the `tableView` (not as a cell, but above the `tableView`) I can't set a height constraint and make it after 0.

[image]

This is the code I use:

```
UIView.animate(withDuration: 2.0, animations: { () -> Void in
  self.infoView.frame = CGRect(x: 0 ,y: 0, width: self.view.frame.width, height: 0)
  self.view.layoutIfNeeded()
})
```

I also tried to set infoView equal to nil (but nothing happened)

Please leave a comment if you don't understand something I said.

Thanks in advance.

Comment: Is it possible to use tableHeaderView and then set its height property to zero with tableHeaderView height ? Like this https://stackoverflow.com/a/34689293/3739902

Comment: Have you checked outlet?
Isn't it nil?

Comment: @user3739902 thank you I tried to set the tableheaderView as nil and did what I wanted, now I will make it with the height to be more beautiful, thanks again

Comment: @mikevorisis no problem, glad it works. If it's not a problem, would you mind marking the answer as correct ? :)

Comment: @user3739902 you have to make an answer to mark it as accepted :P, of course I will as soon as you answer

Comment: @user3739902 Comments are not answers.

Answer (score 0):

Simplest way is hide it, each view has property hidden. https://developer.apple.com/documentation/uikit/uiview/1622585-hidden

Comment: Hi thanks for the answer but if I hide it, it will keep its height and I'll have an empty view.

Answer (score 0):

```
change your code


UIView.animate(withDuration: 2.0, animations: { () -> Void in
            self.infoView.frame = CGRect(x: 0 ,y: 0, width: 0, height: 0)
            self.tableView.contentInsetAdjustmentBehavior = UIScrollViewContentInsetAdjustmentBehavior.automatic
            self.tableView.reloadData()

        })
```

Comment: Hi this doesn't disappear the view it only makes the tableview bigger and the view is now above the cells

Comment: Could you share your class & storyboard??