# line breaks not working on UILabel in tableFooterView

Tags: ios, swift, uitableview, uilabel, tablefooterview

I habe a **tableView** with a **footerView**. It should display a simple label.

In my ViewController, in `viewDidLoad`, I assign the tableFooterView like so:

```
let footerView = MyFooterView(frame: CGRect(x: 0, y: 0, width: tableView.frame.width, height: 0))
tableView.tableFooterView = footerView
```

`MyFooterView` is a UIView with a single label. The label setup looks like so:

```
label.font = someFont
label.adjustsFontForContentSizeCategory = true
label.textColor = .black
label.numberOfLines = 0
label.text = "my super looooooong label that should break some lines but it doesn't."
label.textAlignment = .center
label.translatesAutoresizingMaskIntoConstraints = false
addSubview(label)
NSLayoutConstraint.activate([
    label.leadingAnchor.constraint(equalTo: self.leadingAnchor, constant: 40),
    label.trailingAnchor.constraint(equalTo: self.trailingAnchor, constant: -40),
    label.topAnchor.constraint(equalTo: self.topAnchor, constant: 20),
    label.bottomAnchor.constraint(equalTo: self.bottomAnchor, constant: -20)
])
```

In order to get AutoLayout to work with `MyFooterView`, I call this method inside UIViewControllers `viewDidLayoutSubviews`:

```
func sizeFooterToFit() {
    if let footerView = self.tableFooterView {
        footerView.setNeedsLayout()
        footerView.layoutIfNeeded()

        let height = footerView.systemLayoutSizeFitting(UIView.layoutFittingCompressedSize).height
        var frame = footerView.frame
        frame.size.height = height
        footerView.frame = frame

        self.tableFooterView = footerView
    }
}
```

**Problem:** The lines in the label do not break. I get the following result:

[image: tableFooterView]

**What can I do so that the label has multiple lines?** AutoLayout is working thanks to the method `sizeFooterToFit`. The only thing is that the labels height is only as high as a single line.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

[HERE](https://stackoverflow.com/a/52350172/4085910) is the way how you can achieve it for `tableHeaderView` and with your case you just need to add below code in your `UIViewController` class

```
override func viewWillLayoutSubviews() {
    super.viewWillLayoutSubviews()
    tbl.updateHeaderViewHeight()
}
```

And Helper `extension`

```
extension UITableView {
    func updateHeaderViewHeight() {
        if let header = self.tableFooterView {
            let newSize = header.systemLayoutSizeFitting(CGSize(width: self.bounds.width, height: 0))
            header.frame.size.height = newSize.height
        }
    }
}
```

And remove

```
func sizeFooterToFit() {
    if let footerView = self.tableFooterView {
        footerView.setNeedsLayout()
        footerView.layoutIfNeeded()

        let height = footerView.systemLayoutSizeFitting(UIView.layoutFittingCompressedSize).height
        var frame = footerView.frame
        frame.size.height = height
        footerView.frame = frame

        self.tableFooterView = footerView
    }
}
```

Above code.

And result will be:

[image]

Comment: Thanks. But this does not work with dynamic type. The font changes accordingly, but the height does not change.

Comment: edit: It works with dynamicType, I just have to reload the tableView