# Space between TableViewHeader and Section Header

Tags: ios, swift, uitableview

I need help getting rid of the space between my TableView's main header and a section header.

```
   let tableView: UITableView = {
       let tableView = UITableView(frame: .zero, style: .plain)
       return tableView
   }()

   tableView.tableHeaderView = postView
```

The post view is dynamic so I cannot set the height for that headerView in the delegate method.

I want the postView and the section below it together, but there is the weird space.

[image]

Answer (score 0):

Try this code
[Setting tableHeaderView height dynamically](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/34661793/setting-tableheaderview-height-dynamically/34689293#34689293)

```
override func viewDidLayoutSubviews() {
    super.viewDidLayoutSubviews()

    if let headerView = tableView.tableHeaderView {

        let height = headerView.systemLayoutSizeFitting(UIView.layoutFittingCompressedSize).height
        var headerFrame = headerView.frame

        //Comparison necessary to avoid infinite loop
        if height != headerFrame.size.height {
            headerFrame.size.height = height
            headerView.frame = headerFrame
            tableView.tableHeaderView = headerView
        }
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Try the following:

```
let tableView: UITableView = {
    let tableView = UITableView(frame: .zero, style: .grouped)
    return tableView
}()

tableView.tableHeaderView = postView
```

Comment: Be aware that using a grouped style will also cause the headers to lock to the top cell for each section, rather than allowing the section cells to scroll independently.

Comment: Thanks, I know grouped style always sticks the section header with the cell. If it's not an issue this will work.