# How do I create UITableView header whose height is determined by the height of its label?

Tags: ios, swift

I would like to add a header to my tableView.  This header contains 1 UILabel.  The header height should be calculated based on the number of lines the label has.

In my code, I'm adding constraints with all the edges of the label <> header.  This is my attempt:

```
    //Add header to tableView
    header = UIView()
    header.backgroundColor = UIColor.yellowColor()
    tableView!.tableHeaderView = header

    //Create Label and add it to the header
    postBody = UILabel()
    postBody.text = "The quick brown fox jumps over the lazy dog. The quick brown fox jumps over the lazy dog. The quick brown fox jumps over the lazy dog."
    postBody.font = UIFont(name: "Lato-Regular", size: 16.0)
    postBody.numberOfLines = 0
    postBody.backgroundColor = FlatLime()
    header.addSubview(postBody)

    //Enable constraints for each item
    postBody.translatesAutoresizingMaskIntoConstraints = false
    header.translatesAutoresizingMaskIntoConstraints = false

    //Add constraints to the header and post body
    let postBodyLeadingConstraint = NSLayoutConstraint(item: postBody, attribute: NSLayoutAttribute.Leading, relatedBy: NSLayoutRelation.Equal, toItem: header, attribute: NSLayoutAttribute.Leading, multiplier: 1, constant: 0)
    postBodyLeadingConstraint.active = true

    let postBodyTrailingConstraint = NSLayoutConstraint(item: postBody, attribute: NSLayoutAttribute.Trailing, relatedBy: NSLayoutRelation.Equal, toItem: header, attribute: NSLayoutAttribute.Trailing, multiplier: 1, constant: 0)
    postBodyTrailingConstraint.active = true


    let postBodyTopConstraint = NSLayoutConstraint(item: postBody, attribute: NSLayoutAttribute.Top, relatedBy: NSLayoutRelation.Equal, toItem: header, attribute: NSLayoutAttribute.Top, multiplier: 1, constant: 0)
    postBodyTopConstraint.active = true


    let postBodyBottomConstraint = NSLayoutConstraint(item: postBody, attribute: NSLayoutAttribute.Bottom, relatedBy: NSLayoutRelation.Equal, toItem: header, attribute: NSLayoutAttribute.Bottom, multiplier: 1, constant: 0)
    postBodyBottomConstraint.active = true


    //Calculate header size
    let size = header.systemLayoutSizeFittingSize(UILayoutFittingCompressedSize)
    var frame = header.frame
    frame.size.height = size.height
    header.frame = frame
    tableView!.tableHeaderView = header
    header.layoutIfNeeded()
```

This is my table:

```
    let nib = UINib(nibName: "MessagesTableViewCell", bundle: nil)
    let nibSimple = UINib(nibName: "SimpleMessagesTableViewCell", bundle: nil)
    self.tableView!.registerNib(nib, forCellReuseIdentifier: "MessagesTableViewCell")
    self.tableView!.registerNib(nibSimple, forCellReuseIdentifier: "SimpleMessagesTableViewCell")
    self.tableView!.dataSource = self
    self.tableView!.delegate = self
    self.tableView!.rowHeight = UITableViewAutomaticDimension
    self.tableView!.estimatedRowHeight = 100.0
    self.tableView!.separatorStyle = UITableViewCellSeparatorStyle.None
    self.tableView!.separatorColor = UIColor(hex: 0xf5f5f5)
    self.tableView!.separatorInset = UIEdgeInsetsMake(0, 0, 0, 0)
    self.tableView!.clipsToBounds = true
    self.tableView!.allowsSelection = false
    self.tableView!.allowsMultipleSelection = false
    self.tableView!.keyboardDismissMode = .OnDrag
```

As you can see, the header does not take into account the height of the label (which I did numberOfLines = 0)

[image: Header does not auto-height]

Comment: Can you post your table view primary method code?

Comment: If you set a breakpoint what does the frame look like when you assign it back to the header?

Comment: Are you not missing postBody.translatesAutoresizingMaskIntoConstraints = false ?

Comment: Does it need to be a header, or can you constrain a header view on top of the tableView?

Comment: Also, it doesn't look like you're resizing the label to a certain width. This could drive the height of it. Not sure if you have it somewhere else in the code?

Comment: @DougMead I have constraints on both sides of the label to its superview. Why do I need to set a constraint for width? Also, what do you mea "constrain a header on top of it"? How would that work/look like?

Comment: Get relevant code idea from this blog post:- http://www.programmingcrew.in/2015/09/uitable-view-cell-dynamic-height-ios7.html

Comment: There's a great blog post about this over here http://roadfiresoftware.com/2015/05/how-to-size-a-table-header-view-using-auto-layout-in-interface-builder/. This solves exactly the issue you are facing. Hope this helps.

Comment: did you set word wrapping on the label? You are setting `header.translatesAutoresizingMaskIntoConstraints = false` and then you are changing `frame` of the `header`? That's very strange.

Answer (score 20, accepted):

`UILabel`s take advantage of `UIView`'s `intrinsicContentSize()` to tell auto layout what size they should be. For a multiline label, however, the intrinsic content size is ambiguous; the table doesn't know if it should be short and wide, tall and narrow, or anything in between.

To combat this, `UILabel` has a property called `preferredMaxLayoutWidth`. Setting this tells a multiline label that it should be at most this wide, and allows `intrinsicContentSize()` to figure out and return an appropriate height to match. By not setting the `preferredMaxLayoutWidth` in your example, the label leaves its width unbounded and therefore calculates the height for a long, single line of text.

The only complication with `preferredMaxLayoutWidth` is that you typically don't know what width you want the label to be until auto layout has calculated one for you. For that reason, the place to set it in a view controller subclass (which it looks like your code sample might be from) is in `viewDidLayoutSubviews`:

```
override func viewDidLayoutSubviews() {
    super.viewDidLayoutSubviews()
    postBody.preferredMaxLayoutWidth = CGRectGetWidth(postBody.frame)
    // then update the table header view
    if let header = tableView?.tableHeaderView {
        header.frame.size.height = header.systemLayoutSizeFittingSize(UILayoutFittingCompressedSize).height
        tableView?.tableHeaderView = header
    }
}
```

Obviously, you'll need to add a property for the `postBody` label for this to work.

Let me know if you're not in a `UIViewController` subclass here and I'll edit my answer.

Answer (score 10):

> Implementation using the storyboard

1. In `UItableView` add on `UITableViewCell` new `UIView` and put him `UILabel`
   Connects them via Autolayout
2. In `UILabel` put the number of lines to 0.
3. In `ViewDidLoad` your `UILabel` call a method `sizeToFit()`
   and specify a size for `UIView`, and that will be your HeaderVew `headerView.frame.size.height = headerLabel.frame.size.height`

> Code

```
    @IBOutlet weak var tableView: UITableView!
    @IBOutlet weak var headerView: UIView!
    @IBOutlet weak var headerLabel: UILabel!

    override func viewDidLoad() {
        super.viewDidLoad()

        headerLabel.text = "tableViewdidReceiveMemoryWarningdidReceiveMemoryWarningdidReceiveMemoryWarningdidReceiveMemoryWarningdidReceiveMemoryWarningdidReceiveMemoryWarningdidReceiveMemoryWarningdidReceiveMemoryWarningdidReceiveMemoryWarning"
        headerLabel.sizeToFit()
        headerView.frame.size.height = headerLabel.frame.size.height
    }
```

> ScreenShot

[image]

> TestProject

[test project link](https://www.dropbox.com/s/sp3kgyl3m8x7ox8/TestProject.zip?dl=0)

Answer (score 9):

The first problem we have is that the header cannot be resized by autolayout, for details, see [Is it possible to use AutoLayout with UITableView's tableHeaderView?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16471846/is-it-possible-to-use-autolayout-with-uitableviews-tableheaderview)

Therefore, we have to calculate the height of the header manually, for example:

```
@IBOutlet var table: UITableView!

var header: UIView?
var postBody: UILabel?

override func viewDidLoad() {
    super.viewDidLoad()

    let header = UIView()
    // don't forget to set this
    header.translatesAutoresizingMaskIntoConstraints = true
    header.backgroundColor = UIColor.yellowColor()

    let postBody = UILabel()
    postBody.translatesAutoresizingMaskIntoConstraints = false
    postBody.text = "The quick brown fox jumps over the lazy dog. The quick brown fox jumps over the lazy dog. The quick brown fox jumps over the lazy dog."
    postBody.font = UIFont.systemFontOfSize(16.0)

    // don't forget to set this
    postBody.lineBreakMode = .ByWordWrapping
    postBody.numberOfLines = 0

    header.addSubview(postBody)

    let leadingConstraint = NSLayoutConstraint(item: postBody, attribute: NSLayoutAttribute.Leading, relatedBy: NSLayoutRelation.Equal, toItem: header, attribute: NSLayoutAttribute.Leading, multiplier: 1, constant: 0)
    let trailingConstraint = NSLayoutConstraint(item: postBody, attribute: NSLayoutAttribute.Trailing, relatedBy: NSLayoutRelation.Equal, toItem: header, attribute: NSLayoutAttribute.Trailing, multiplier: 1, constant: 0)
    let topConstraint = NSLayoutConstraint(item: postBody, attribute: NSLayoutAttribute.Top, relatedBy: NSLayoutRelation.Equal, toItem: header, attribute: NSLayoutAttribute.Top, multiplier: 1, constant: 0)
    let bottomConstraint = NSLayoutConstraint(item: postBody, attribute: NSLayoutAttribute.Bottom, relatedBy: NSLayoutRelation.Equal, toItem: header, attribute: NSLayoutAttribute.Bottom, multiplier: 1, constant: 0)

    header.addConstraints([leadingConstraint, trailingConstraint, topConstraint, bottomConstraint])

    self.table.tableHeaderView = header

    self.header = header
    self.postBody = postBody
}

override func viewDidLayoutSubviews() {
    super.viewDidLayoutSubviews()

    let text = postBody!.attributedText!

    let height = text.boundingRectWithSize(
        CGSizeMake(table.bounds.size.width, CGFloat.max),
        options: [.UsesLineFragmentOrigin],
        context: nil
    ).height

    header!.frame.size.height = height
}
```

You might also want to use the code in [stefandouganhyde's answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/36941469/669586). It does not really matter how you calculate the height. The point is that autolayout won't work automatically for `tableHeaderView`.

Result:

[image: resulting table]

Answer (score 2):

We use NSLayoutManager to quickly estimate the height for items that need to resize based on the text. This is the basic idea:

```
override class func estimatedHeightForItem(text: String, atWidth width: CGFloat) -> CGFloat {

    let storage = NSTextStorage(string: text!)
    let container = NSTextContainer(size: CGSize(width: width, height: CGFloat.max))
    let layoutManager = NSLayoutManager()
    layoutManager.addTextContainer(container)
    storage.addLayoutManager(layoutManager)
    storage.addAttribute(NSFontAttributeName, value: UIFont.Body, range: NSRange(location: 0, length: storage.length))
    container.lineFragmentPadding = 0.0

    return layoutManager.usedRectForTextContainer(container).size.height 
}
```

[Beslan's answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/36956742/5499522) is probably a better fit for your use case, but I find it nice to have more control how the layout is handled.

Answer (score -1):

//may be it will help for you.

```
header = UIView(frame: CGRectMake(tableview.frame.origin.x,tableview.frame.origin.y, tableview.frame.size.width, 40))
header.backgroundColor = UIColor.yellowColor()

//Create Label and add it to the header
postBody = UILabel(frame: header.frame)
postBody.text = "The quick brown fox jumps over the lazy dog. The quick brown fox jumps over the lazy dog. The quick brown fox jumps over the lazy dog."
postBody.font = UIFont(name: "Lato-Regular", size: 16.0)
postBody.numberOfLines = 0
postBody.backgroundColor = FlatLime()
header.addSubview(postBody)

let maximumLabelSize: CGSize = CGSizeMake(postBody.size.width, CGFloat.max);

let options: NSStringDrawingOptions  = NSStringDrawingOptions.UsesLineFragmentOrigin
let context: NSStringDrawingContext = NSStringDrawingContext()
        context.minimumScaleFactor = 0.8
        let attr: Dictionary = [NSFontAttributeName: postBody.font!]
        var size: CGSize? = postBody.text?.boundingRectWithSize(maximumLabelSize, options:options, attributes: attr, context: context).size

let frame = header.frame
frame.size.height = size?.height
header.frame = frame
postBody.frame = frame
tableView!.tableHeaderView = header
```

Answer (score -2):

you can calculate the height of a label by using its string

```
let labelWidth = label.frame.width
let maxLabelSize = CGSize(width: labelWidth, height: CGFloat.max)
let actualLabelSize = label.text!.boundingRectWithSize(maxLabelSize, options: [.UsesLineFragmentOrigin], attributes: [NSFontAttributeName: label.font], context: nil)
let labelHeight = actualLabelSize.height
```

Comment: Well, that's for section header, not for table header. A very different thing.